# Do you have to include multi-processing in python code that you run on an MS Azure VM?

Tags: python, azure, multiprocessing, virtual-machine, gil

Quick questions here:

I have an azure VM set up with Anaconda and Spyder as an IDE.  The code that I would like to run with a higher virtual RAM on my local machine is currently NOT using the multiprocesssing library and is still a slave to the specter of GIL on my laptop.   I would obviously have to include multi-processing to get the code to use more than one core on my own machine.

The question is do you have to do the same to get the advantage of multiple virtual cores on MS Azure, or will the interface simply batch whatever you run out as if GIL never existed in the VM World?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It would be the same. While Virtual, to the underlying OS, they are still separate cores for you to leverage.